# In Android EditText how to get the cursor position in an OnTouchListener after it is set

Tags: android-edittext

I am building a text editing component that I need to capture the character position after the user touches the screen.

I have added an OnTouchListener, however what I am finding is that I am getting the original character position, before the user had touched the screen.

Is there any way to reverse the order so that my OnTouchListener gets called *after* the default one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I am letting the OnTouchListener schedule a thread for 100MS in the future, which give the Android enough time to position the cursor before my process requests the cursor position.

Quite a hack but it works (at least on my Samsung Galaxy S2), I would love if someone could post a better reply.